# How do I make the square-bracketed numbers in my bibliography equally sized when using the Roboto font?

Tags: fonts, biblatex, ieee-style

when I am using the Roboto font, the bibliography numbering is not equally sized: using this minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=ieee, sorting=none]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}

 \begin{filecontents*}{./example.bib}
   @article{nice,
   author={B. C. Dull},
   title={All functions are {$C^{\infty}$}},
   journal={J. False Results},
   year={2033},
   }
   @article{nice2,
   author={B. C. Dull},
   title={All functions are {$C^{\infty}$}},
   journal={J. False Results},
   year={2033},
   }
 \end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{example.bib} 

\begin{document}
   Test~\cite{nice,nice2}.
   \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is something like this:

[image]

How to I make them equally sized?

Comment: It appears that `1` and `2` have different widths in the font you use. There isn't anything `biblatex` can do about that. What exactly would you like to see done about this?

Comment: Which engine are you using? pdflatex? Or lualatex/xelatex?

Comment: You can use tabular-numbers (`\usepackage[sfdefault,tabular]{roboto}`). The main question is if you want them everywhere in your document or only at the bib numbers.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thats exactly what I wanted! I should have read the docs first I guess. Thank you!

Comment: Even with tabular numbers you will still see a similar effect for labels with different numbers of digits (`1` vs `12`). Of course this may not bother you as much ...

Comment: Yeah sorry didn't know that :) Deleted the edit!

Comment: When I first read the question, I thought it meant that the *height* of the brackets wasn't the same,  That was mistaken, so I edited the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use tabular numbers everywhere, which you can do by loading the `roboto` package with the `tabular` option:

```
\usepackage[sfdefault,tabular]{roboto}
```

Or you can change the type of numbers just for the labels in the bibliography by adding this after loading `biblatex`:

**For `pdflatex`**

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifbibliography
    {\fontfamily{Roboto-TLF}\selectfont}
    {}#1}
```

**For `xelatex` or `lualatex`**

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifbibliography
    {\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Monospaced}}
    {}#1}
```